# My wife's AOC monitor won't display anything

Tags: display

This morning my wife went to her PC, to log in (we leave our PC's on 24/7), but the AOC 2243W monitor wouldn't wake up or whatever. All it would say is "No signal". I bought this monitor about 6 months ago, so I'm surprised that it would be failing so fast, if it is. All cables are fine, it's connected to the DVI. The only way I could get the monitor to display anything was to do a hard boot of the PC; not something I care to do on a regular basis.

What could be wrong? What should I look into, to try and fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm.  Well, I had to guess that you were in the US, when I went to AOC's web site to look up their warranty information.  Then, once I was there, AOC doesn't acknowledge the existence of a 2243W.  There's an e2243FW, for example.  At any rate, here is what their warranty information has to say about this...

> AOC warrants this product to be free from defects in material and workmanship for a period of three (3) years limited (panel 1 year, parts and labor 3) after the original date of consumer purchase. During this period, EPI ( EPI is the abbreviation of Envision Peripherals, Inc. ) will, at its option, either repair the defective product with new or rebuilt parts, or replace it with a new or rebuilt product at no charge except as *stated below. The parts or product that are replaced become the property of EPI.

They go on to detail what you should do if you can't deliver it in person, etc.

My point?  If your monitor ceases to function mysteriously after 6 months of use, and you've done nothing to cause this malfunction, then you should be thinking **warranty** not **do-it-yourself**.  However, if you wish to determine if this is really an issue with the monitor or not, you should connect a different monitor to the computer and see if the symptoms persist.  If they persist on a different monitor, then the issue is with your computer.  If the symptoms vanish, then it is indeed the monitor.

From there, you would need to trace back to see if you can identify when the problem started, and if there were any OS updates that are responsible, or what might be causing the computer NOT to wake from sleep.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need to update your videocard drivers or it automatically did and your drivers is causing the problem. either or, it definitely sounds like videocard drivers that need to be reinstalled